# Word Framed in Context

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english, vocabulary, literature

> For a split second, Uncle Vernon stood framed in the doorway; then he
> let out a bellow like an angry bull and dived at Harry, grabbing him
> by the ankle.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*

What does the word "framed" mean in this context?

In Cambridge Dictionary, the meaning is "to be between a border", but it doesn't make sense here sense it's a Person.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the verb *to frame* in a dictionary?

Comment: You have to show us what dictionary definition didn't make sense to you here, and why not. Then we can help you.  Make sure to look for several possible senses.

Comment: You realize that it's called a door frame in English, right? It's not just for paintings.

Comment: A duplicate has been answered on ELL.

Comment: @tchrist: We seem to have ended up trying to close OP's ***first*** posting of this question in favour of the same question posted an hour later. Can you not use some "magic mod" fu to unilaterally delete one of them, since this isn't the normal "closed as a duplicate" situation? I guess I mean *...and transfer any answers on the deleted copy to the preserved copy*, but I understand that may be putting you to quite a bit of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The wood or other material that stays fixed around a door to support it is called the **door frame**.

So if someone was **framed in the doorway** it means they were standing in the doorway under the door frame of an open door. The door frame created a visual outline around the person similar to the way a picture frame outlines the subject of its picture.

Comment: FYI, this question has been closed as a dupe of a cross-post. Feel free to repost your answer on the other one, linked at the top